# Typescript overload interface attribute

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript

Imagine I have a bunch of payload options like:

```
interface IOne {
  type: 'One',
  payload: {
    name: string,
    age: number
  }
}

interface ITwo {
  type: 'Two',
  payload: string
}

declare type TBoth = IOne | ITwo;
```

So I can receive one of the two above as parameter. I want the typescript to be able to recognize the parameters of each type when using a `switch` for example.

The problem I'm having is when I'm trying to **Create** the object.

```
const value = req.body?.message; // just an example
const test: TBoth = {
  type: value ? 'One' : 'Two,  // <--- Now it should autocomplete/suggest the rights parameters based on this attribute.
}
```

I get:

> Types of property 'type' are incompatible.
> Type '"One" | "Two"' is not assignable to type '"Two"'.

Is it possible?

Comment: https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/narrowing.html 
here there are lot of tips on how to do it, in your case you should check the type of your interface for searched behaviour

Comment: Since all your interfaces have a literal string on its `type` property, TypeScript can figure out the right type if you check `if (obj.type === 'Two')`. It's called [discriminating unions](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/unions-and-intersections.html#discriminating-unions)

Comment: Thanks guys! I updated the questions with more details. THe problem I'm having is when trying to create the object, because at creation it can be any of the possibilities.

Answer (score 2):

### You can narrow the types of [discriminated unions](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/unions-and-intersections.html#discriminating-unions) like this:

```
const doSomething = (test: TBoth) => {
  if(test.type === `One`) {
    // hover the below `test` with VSCode you will see:
    //   (parameter) test: IOne
    handleIOne(test)
  } else {
    // hover the below `test` with VSCode you will see:
    //   (parameter) test: ITwo
    handleITwo(test)
  }
}
```

See a [live example](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgJIHkQoN4ChkHJgCeADhAFzIDkmE1ANPoaXMQDYD2cAJlXoUHIQcALaVkAZzBRQAcyZDCcORJABXUQCNozAgF9ch3KEixEKVABUA7p2QDCJclWq3OjPclYdufKTLyRrghCJwg0sg8nADKnOJgABbyyAC8yAAUkNJUaHTIAD5o7gCUaQB8Dl7AMJnZYAB0ziiprcgABnTtZY5KYRGc7BANXHJZENINPly8DSoQJQDcXvrIEOySOF6C-ZKDw6Pjk9N+SyvBIdFxCckgY9hEZBK0WIzebDP+D-NUAIwATAxhGIJAAiABSiAA1qDkKt9GcrvEIEl5BkHs1XO43ideFRQQBNCDEiawhHLIA)